# iOS dispatch_get_global_queue nested inside dispatch_get_main_queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I've inherited a codebase that's using the following structure for threading:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
        //Several AFNetworking Server calls...
    })
})
```

I'm not very experienced with threading, so I'm trying to figure out what the possible intention behind this structure. Why grab the main queue only to access another queue immediately? Is this a common practice? For a little more context, this code is executed in an `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification, making several necessary service calls.

Is this structure safe? Essentially my goal is to make the service calls without blocking the UI. Any help or input is appreciated.

Comment: Is the `dispatch_async` to the main queue the first such dispatch in the method the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` triggers? I could be wrong, but I don't think it's possible for this to ever be executed off the main queue. Also, you should check that the networking actually blocks the main thread -- most of the AFNetworking stuff I've seen does the networking asynchronously, then calls a completion block -- you may only need to dispatch back to the main queue from there.

Comment: @BenPious - Thanks for your comment. Yes, the `dispatch_async` to the main queue is the first dispatch in `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. Yeah I knew AFNetworking did some queue-handling of it's own, so I'm not sure how these explicit dispatches factor in.

Comment: There is serious code smell here. On the surface, it's patently absurd to asynchronously dispatch asynchronous AFNetworking calls (much less, doing it twice). Having said that, there are times where one is tempted do things like this, but this doesn't seem like one of those, and patterns like this suggest a general instability of design, imho.

Comment: @Rob - What would be an example of a more stable design? Simply making the calls without dispatching any threads?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but it sounds to me like everything in the example you posted apart from the AFNetworking calls are unnecessary.

Comment: I agree. I'd be inclined to lose both of those asynchronous dispatches and rely upon the inherent asynchronous nature of AFNetworking. The only reason I might hesitate is if you're building really complicated requests that take more than a few milliseconds to build. We can't say without seeing what that code is doing. But benchmark it and see. I want to give that developer the benefit of the doubt, but in the absence of evidence or code samples, I'd suggest simplifying that code.

Answer (score 2):

So I think this is an interesting few lines that somebody decided to write, so let's break down what's happening here (I may be breaking things down too much, sorry in advance, it just helps my own train of thought)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), dispatch_block_t block)
```

This will put the `block` as a task on the main queue (which you the code is already running in), then immediately continue executing the code in the rest of the method (If he had wanted to wait for the `block` task to finish before continuing, he'd have made a `dispatch_sync` call instead).
The main queue is serial, so it will perform these tasks exactly in this order:

- go ahead and execute the `block` after the end of the current method (the end of the run loop for the current task)
- execute any other tasks that may have been asynchronously added to the main queue before you `dispatch_async` your `block` task into the queue
- execute the `block` task

Now `block` just dispatches another task to the high priority global queue.
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), block2)`

The `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH` is a concurrent queue-- so if you were to dispatch multiple tasks to this queue, it could potentially do them in parallel, depending on several system factors.

Your old co-worker wanted to make sure the networking calls in `block2` were done ASAP

Because `block` is calling `dispatch_async` (which returns immediately), `block` task finishes, allowing the main queue to execute the next task in the queue.

The net result so far is that `block2` is queued into the high priority global queue.  After it executes, and your network calls complete, callback methods will be called and yadayada

...So what is the order of what's happening?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
        //Several AFNetworking Server calls...
    })
})
//moreCode
```

1) moreCode executes
2) `block` executes (adds `block2` with network calls onto global queue)
3/4) Next task in main queue executes
4/3) Network task in global queue executes

The order of which would happen first may vary between 3 and 4, but that's concurrency for you :)

So unless old coworker wanted `moreCode` to execute first before **adding** the network calls to a global queue, you can go ahead and remove that initial `dispatch_async` into the main queue.
Assuming it looks like they wanted the network calls done ASAP, there probably is no reason to delay the addition of those networking tasks into a global queue.

Open to any input ^^.  My experience involves reading all of the documentation on GCD today, then deciding to look at some GCD tagged questions